# Why different answers for the same logic in datetime conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, date

The output of converted date is '20210514'

```
input_date = '14-05-2021' # 14th May 2021
converted_date = (pd.to_datetime(input_date).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

But if I use the same logic below, why is it coming up like '20220601' (1st June 2022)? The output I expect is '20220106'.

```
input_date = '06-01-2022' # 6th Jan 2022
converted_date = (pd.to_datetime(input_date).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Comment: Pandas is guessing the data format. There clearly isn't a month 14 so the first is obvious, but the second could be ``DD-MM-YYYY`` or ``MM-DD-YYYY``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a format for the input date string so pandas has to guess at it. `06-01-2022` is ambiguous: it could be month-day-year or day-month-year.

[`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) has a `dayfirst` argument that defaults to false. Since `06` is a valid month, it is being parsed as a month. `14` is *not* a valid month, so pandas figures out it should be the day.

Try this instead:

```py
input_date = '06-01-2022' # 6th Jan 2022
converted_date = (pd.to_datetime(input_date, dayfirst=True).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

You can also pass in a `format` if you want to be really specific.